# Is there a way to have .my.cnf settings for mysqladmin and mysql standard console?

Tags: command-line, mysql, my.cnf, mysqladmin

My Ubuntu Linux development machine I have the following `~/.my.cnf` file which is a great time saver when connecting to `mysql` from the command line.

```
[client]
auto-rehash
safe-updates
host     = localhost
user     = root
password = mysql
prompt   = "[\d]>"
```

However, when I type `mysqladmin` I receive the error

```
mysqladmin: unknown option '--auto-rehash'
```

The problem is some of the lines in the `.my.cnf` file aren't applicable to `mysqladmin` and `mysqldump`.

Is there a way to specify configuration options in `.my.cnf` such that they will apply to either `mysql` or `mysqladmin`, `mysqldump` or both?

If not, how do I start a `mysqldump` from command line and specify to it not to read the `.my.cnf` settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put those options in a separate group, subject to the selected application:

```
[client]
safe-updates
host     = localhost
user     = root
password = mysql
prompt   = "[\d]>"

[mysql]
auto-rehash
```

Read more about usage of config file on [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html).

Comment: This is the right idea, but backwards... auto-rehash *breaks* mysqladmin, and belongs in a `[mysql]` section.  `[client]` should only be used for options that are valid for all client utilities.